# Reduce react-native Android APK size by removing lib (.so)

Tags: android, react-native, apk, release

I saw a post which showing an 'Analyzed apk' result like this, I'm not sure whether the author built with react-native or not. Full post is in [this link](https://hackernoon.com/how-we-brought-down-the-size-of-our-app-from-31-mb-to-2-6-mb-and-what-it-taught-us-3a75963317f9)

[image: two muppets]

Note that his 'lib' folder is only 18.5KB, and this is the result for my smallest apk (armeabi-v7a):

[image: two muppets]
What I've been applying so far (android/app/build.gradle):

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    resConfigs 'my-language'
  }
  splits {
    abi {
      enable true
      universalApk false
      include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
    }
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
      shrinkResources true
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

I was able to reduce my apk(s) to about 10mb, but the 'lib' folder is 5.7mb, 58% size of APK. If I can remove 'lib' folder or compress them like that post, I can even reduce more size.

Is there a way to do it?

***NOTE: I've tried to exclude entire armeabi-v7a 'lib' folder by:

```
android { 
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a'
    }
}
```

My apk is about 5MB but it's crash when open

Comment: did you get any solution? I have also the same issue of large size apk

Comment: for me applying just some tweaks in app/build.gradle is enough for small size, but I wonder if I can get even smaller like what in the post